# 5 digit numbers in ascending order

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many $5$ digit numbers are there such that digits are in ascending order ?

I think it must be $5 \times 6^4$ ,
But I'm not sure. I would love to see an algorithm to solve this kind of problems.

Comment: Do you allow repeated digits?

Comment: Once you choose the digits, there's only one way to arrange them.

Comment: Can you answer the question for one and two digit numbers, then three? That might lead you to a solution.

Comment: @saulspatz assuming no repeating digits

Comment: I think no repeating digits, that wouldn't really be acceding order

Comment: @RushabhMehta I don't agree with that.  There's only one number once the digits are chosen.

Comment: Yes obviously only one once digits are chosen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two answers here, depending on the criteria you hold.

If you require that the digits are **strictly** ascending, i.e., repeated digits are not allowed, this question becomes rather simple, as for each combination of digits, there is only "valid" ordering of numbers. Hence, we simply take the combination of 5 digits from the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 (no 0 because a number can't start with 0). This gives us $${9\choose 5} = 126$$

If you allow repeated digits, then it's a bit more tricky. If the digits are $a,b,c,d,e$, we define $u=a-1, v=b-a,w=c-b, x=d-c,y=e-d, z=9-e$. This is useful because $$u+v+w+x+y+z=8$$ and each of these numbers must be $\geq0$. So, we use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) to get ${13\choose 5} = 1287$.

P.S. You could also use stars and bars for the strictly ascending case! You should try it out to see whether you can replicate the same solution I've derived.